# Why does my foreach addEventListener is not adding the event?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm doing a modal gallery, and I think that I have everything pretty much functional but when I click on the images i'm pretty sure the JS doesn't work.
Im pretty sure it's not getting the images from the querySelectorAll, but idk I could be wrong, I just can't get this to work.

Here's my code:

```js
var modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
var previews = document.querySelectorAll("#gallery img");
var original = document.querySelector(".fullImg");
var imgText = document.querySelector(".caption");

previews.forEach((preview) => {
  preview.addEventListener("click", () => {
    modal.classList.add("open");
  })
});

modal.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("modal")) {
    modal.classList.remove("open");
  }
});
```

```css
.modal
  {
      background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      opacity: 0;
      pointer-events: none;

  }
  .modal.open
  {
      opacity: 1;
      pointer-events: all;
  }
  .fullImg
  {
      position: absolute;
      height: 70%;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.5);
      transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  }
  .fullImg.open
  {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  }
  .modal p
  {
    color: white;
    font-size: 2rem;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -5%);
  }
```

```html
<div id="gallery">
            <div class="imagemTexto">
                <img class="GaleriaEffect imagem1" alt ="Comboio de madeira" src="img/brinquedos/comboio/Grupo de máscara 10.png">
                <div class="texto">
                    <h2>Wood Truckain</h2>
                    </br>
                    <p>Ora camião, ora comboio!</p><p>Estas são as duas possibilidades de montagem deste brinquedo totalmente contruído em madeira de pinho.</p> Podendo alterar as peças para construir a forma de camião ou de comboio, a criatividade das crianças é estimulada.</p>
                    </br>
                    <h3>Diogo Rocha</h3>
                </div>
            </div> 
            </br>
            <a class="AntN">&#10094;</a>
            <a class="ProxS">&#10095;</a>
            <img class="GaleriaEffect imagem2" alt ="Comboio de madeira" src="img/brinquedos/comboio/Grupo de máscara 11.png">
            <img class="GaleriaEffect imagem3" alt ="Comboio de madeira" src="img/brinquedos/comboio/Grupo de máscara 12.png">
        </div>
<div class="modal">
        <img src="" class="fullImg" />
        <p class="caption"></p>`
    </div>
```

Im gettin really desperate, i've tried so many diferent things but it ain't working

Comment: In the example given it is `.modal` which doesn't exist.

Comment: oh I forgot the add the rest of the html code, its "<div class="modal">
            <img src="" class="fullImg" />
            <p class="caption"></p>
        </div>

Comment: May you edit the question example?

Comment: Yeap, just did it

Comment: Now the modal does seem to open when the text "Comboio de madeira" is clicked. (This is the image alt text) --- Please make sure the example shows the issue you're having. See [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You are **not** setting the **src of the image in the modal**. You have to set this as well:

```js
previews.forEach((preview) => {
    preview.addEventListener("click", () => {
        modal.classList.add("open");
        modal.querySelector('img').src = preview.src; //Update the src of the modal image with the src
    })
});
```

Comment: Another debug tipp: You can check what's in your javascript variables by just typing their name into the console as well as checking the DOM in your browser (You can do this with right click on the page and 'Inspect').